# onClickListener in RecyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I want to set up an onClickListener within my RecyclerView adapter so I can easily refer to the other views to retrieve their tags.

Is it possible to set up an onClickListener in a RecyclerView adapter? How would I do it? Would it affect performance?

Here is my RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class PostRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Post> mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        public LinearLayout mainLayout;
        public TextView username;
        public ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(LinearLayout view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

            mainLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
            username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }

    public PostRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Post> myDataset) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public PostRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((LinearLayout) view);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Post postItem = mDataset.get(position);

        holder.username.setText(postItem.getUserame());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would like to suggest a much simpler approach than the one given above**.
in your adapter you would have written static view holder class right for that add the following code

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
       // your views declared here           
        CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);                
           // your view initialised here
              cardView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
              cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.card_view:
                    // your logic
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

by doing so you can handle individual click of your layout as well as the entire layout click

Comment: I think you forget setting listener

Answer (score 0):

You can use GestureDetector for this. This is very simple to use :

Create A class RecyclerTouchListener :

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }


    public interface ClickListener {

        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

}
```

and you can use this class as follow :

```
rvFilterOptions = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvCommon);
        rvFilterOptions.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvFilterOptions.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(),
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rvFilterOptions.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        rvFilterOptions.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), rvFilterOptions, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

// Perform click operation  and you can get post item from array using position
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

// Perform Long click operation 
            }
        }));
```

Note : Concept is taken from [LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html)

Comment: Is it necessary to completely overhaul the adapter using GestureDetector just to get a simple onClickListener event for a view?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener.html

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest implementation but this will be inside recyclerviews adapter. If you want to get row item clicklistener in activity then use Interface.

```
public class PostRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Post> mDataset;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
        public LinearLayout mainLayout;
        public TextView username;
        public ImageView image;
        public View mRowItem;   

        public ViewHolder(LinearLayout view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
            mRowItem = view;
            mainLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_view);
            username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }

    public PostRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Post> myDataset) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public PostRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder((LinearLayout) view);


        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Post postItem = mDataset.get(position);

        holder.username.setText(postItem.getUserame());

        //Whole row item
        holder.mRowItem.setTag(position);
        holder.mRowItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                  // handle your row item click.
              }
           });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```