# Why is the onClick method of my RecyclerView.ViewHolder not called sometimes?

Tags: java, android

My `ViewHolder` implements `View.OnClickListener` as it's suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33294720/9146508). Apart from that I double checked that my adapter class is similar to the examples in the official documentation.

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View view;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.view = view;
    }

    public View getView() {
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

But if I'm testing my app I observe this really odd behavior: If I'm tapping on a row that is visible at startup, the `onClick` method is executed as expected. Now I scroll down making some other rows visible. I tap somewhere and nothing happens, the second tap – if it's on the same row or not – works again. If I scroll back to the top the same thing occurs and I have to tap twice to get my `onClick` method called.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT:** Full code, now setting the listener in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
public class ComposersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComposersAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View view;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.view = view;
        }

        public View getView() {
            return view;
        }
    }

    private final String EXTRA_COMPOSER_ID = "composerId";
    private List<Composer> composers;

    public ComposersAdapter(List<Composer> composers) {
        this.composers = composers;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.text_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        View view = holder.getView();
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(composers.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.getView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context context = view.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ComposerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COMPOSER_ID, holder.getAdapterPosition());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return composers.size();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** The issue seems to be connected to the toolbar of the activity the RecyclerView resides in. I have set `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` and if I remove that the problem isn't there anymore. Maybe this has something to do with the toolbar capturing the touch events? I'm not experienced enough to examine that myself.

Comment: why not have it done in onBindViewHolder?  instead of having a click listener here, try having one on the root view in the bind method

Comment: You are right, that's cleaner. But the problem stays.

Comment: Sorry I just saw the Kushan's comment now. @Elias, Please provide the full code for the adapter, I think you might be holding/assigning view references incorrectly.

Comment: I updated the question to include the full code.

Comment: "I have to tap twice to get my onClick method called", it looks like that the first tap is to require focus and the second tap actually triggers the ```onClick``` method. You could call ```recyclerView.requestFocus()``` in ```onBindViewHolder```.(You can get recyclerView from ```onAttachedToRecyclerView``` method)

Comment: Please look at my updates to the question, your suggestion didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the click listener in 
`onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)`.

```
onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                  // start some activity
             }
});
}
```

On Bind View Holder is when a viewholder is properly bound to the adapter and individual instances of the view are available here.

```
holder.itemView
```

will give you reference to the viewHolder's view instance.
As a result, you don't `getView()` like methods in ViewHolder.

Comment: How could `holder.setOnClickListener` work? You probably meant `view.setOnClickListener` after getting the view from the holder, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, you are correct @Elias !! I was typing out of my mind, sorry! I just updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, I updated my code, but the issue is still there. Thanks anyway for clarification!

Comment: Did you remove the getView() and replace all of it's it's usages with holder.itemView() ?

Comment: I have put `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener` and it doesn't change anything. What would we the difference?

Answer (score 1):

A **ViewHolder** describes an item view and metadata about its place within the **[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html)**.

**RecyclerView.Adapter** implementations should subclass ViewHolder and add fields for caching potentially expensive *findViewById(int)* results.

I have similar kind of issues in project, I have done some sample, you can look that might help to solve your issue.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Ad> adsList= new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;
    static OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    //Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        @BindView(R.id.mainHolder)
        public RelativeLayout placeHolder;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_ad_name)
        public TextView tvAdName;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_no_of_rating)
        public TextView tvNoOfRating;

        @BindView(R.id.tv_minOs)
        public TextView tvMinOs;

        @BindView(R.id.iv_product_thumbnail)
        public ImageView ivPrductThumbnail;


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
            placeHolder.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getPosition());
            }
        }

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    //Provide a suitable constructor
    public ProductAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }
    public void setAd(List<Ad> aList) {
        adsList.clear();
        adsList.addAll(aList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    //Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ProductAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        //Creating a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_list_items,parent,false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    //Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        Ad ad = adsList.get(position);
        holder.tvAdName.setText(ad.getProductName());
        holder.tvNoOfRating.setText(ad.getNumberOfRatings());
        holder.tvMinOs.setText(ad.getMinOSVersion());

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(ad.getProductThumbnail())
                .into(holder.ivPrductThumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adsList.size();
    }
}
```

Full workable code link [**here**](https://github.com/dharmakshetri/DigitalTrubineTechTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/digitaltrubinetechtest/adapter/ProductAdapter.java). and **[link2](https://github.com/dharmakshetri/Android-API-Demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/apidemos/adapter/GitHubAdapter.java)**.

**Edit**: you might have to declare **textview** inside the **ViewHolder** class.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help either. Caching the views shouldn't be required as setting the text is working as expected and putting the actual click listener somewhere else like you (btw, you should have mentioned that it's in MainActivity.java) doesn't change anything. I have the feeling that I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: can you please check this: https://github.com/dharmakshetri/Android-API-Demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/apidemos/adapter/GitHubAdapter.java

Comment: I dont know this will work or not, however can you please try by removing `static` from here public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {}.